# Is there anyway to use load and after function at the same time

Tags: jquery

let's say i have this html dom

```
<body>
  <div id="divId">
    <span>John,</span>
    <span>Karl,</span>
    <span>Brandon,</span>

    <span>Sam</span>
  </div>
```

i want to load a span child ***after*** the **last child** , i want to something like this

```
$("#divId span:last-child").after().load('http://localhost/testing/getter.php');
```

how do i use this after with load function

Thanks

Comment: What should `getter.php` return?

Comment: <span>newly added span</span> for example i want append a new child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/testing/getter.php',
    context: $('#divId')
}).done(function(data) {
    this.append(data);
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/mfKvc/1/

Comment: nice idea,well it's working but why it's adding multiples as i keep clicking on it, means first time it adds one span that's gr8, but then it after second click it adds two span and son onn....well thanks..if u can answer this it will be grt

Comment: @SandeepKumar - Clicking on what? You don't mention any click events in your question. If you can include that code, I may be able to help you. I've updated my question with a jsFiddle so you can see it in action. When I click on the "Append" link it just adds one new span each time.

Comment: yeah but on click event of  a button

Comment: i'll accept your answer if i don't get the way i asked,your innovation is very good, but i was trying that way, anyways for now +1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('<span>').load('http://localhost/testing/getter.php').insertAfter("#divId span:last-child");
```

Comment: firstly thanks for response and it worked in some way but it add another span ,that is not what i need...